# XSL if test starts-with

Tags: xslt, xpath, xpath-2.0

Given this piece of XML

```
<dc:date>info:eu-repo/date/embargoEnd/2013-06-12</dc:date>
<dc:date>2012-07-04</dc:date>
```

I should need with XSL to output only the year of the string **not starting with** `info:eu-repo`.
I'm trying this way, but it doesn't work. I'm wrong with the `for-each`?

```
<xsl:if test="not(starts-with('dc:date', 'info:eu-repo'))">
                <xsl:for-each select="dc:date">
                    <publicationYear>
                        <xsl:variable name="date" select="."/>
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring($date, 0, 5)"/>
                    </publicationYear>
                </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:if>
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I guess you don't need `'` in your `start-with` query, and you may want to iterate over dates slightly differently:

```
    <xsl:for-each select="dc:date">
         <xsl:variable name="date" select="."/>
         <xsl:if test="not(starts-with($date, 'info:eu-repo'))">
                <publicationYear>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring($date, 0, 5)"/>
                </publicationYear>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Note that you could combine the condition **xsl:if** with the **xsl:for-each** itself to simplify things.... `<xsl:for-each select="dc:date[not(starts-with(., 'info:eu-repo'))]">`

Answer (score 2):

You could also use a `template-match` to get what you want, for example:

```
<xsl:template match="date[not(starts-with(.,'info:eu-repo'))]">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

I have this input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<list>
<date>info:eu-repo/date/embargoEnd/2013-06-12</date>
<date>2012-07-04</date>
</list>
```

and apply this XSLT to it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="text() | @*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="date[not(starts-with(.,'info:eu-repo'))]">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and I get this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>2012-07-04
```

Answer (score 2):

**Use** (assuming the provided XML fragment is elements that are children of the current node and there is only one element with the desired property):

```
substring-before(*[not(starts-with(., 'info:eu-repo'))], '-')
```

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <xsl:copy-of select=
     "substring-before(*[not(starts-with(., 'info:eu-repo'))], '-') "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied to the following XML document** (the provided fragment wrapped in a single top element and the namespace declared):

```
<t xmlns:dc="some:dc">
    <dc:date>info:eu-repo/date/embargoEnd/2013-06-12</dc:date>
    <dc:date>2012-07-04</dc:date>
</t>
```

**the XPath expression is evaluated off the top element and the result of this evaluation is copied to the output**:

```
2012
```

---

**II. More than one element with the desired property**:

In this case It isn't possible to produce the desired data with a single XPath 1.0 expression.

This XSLT transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="*[not(starts-with(., 'info:eu-repo'))]/text()">
     <xsl:copy-of select="substring-before(., '-') "/>
==============  
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document**:

```
<t xmlns:dc="some:dc">
    <dc:date>info:eu-repo/date/embargoEnd/2013-06-12</dc:date>
    <dc:date>2012-07-04</dc:date>
    <dc:date>info:eu-repo/date/embargoEnd/2013-06-12</dc:date>
    <dc:date>2011-07-05</dc:date>
</t>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
2012
==============  
 2011
==============
```

---

**III. XPath 2.0 one-liner**

```
*[not(starts-with(., 'info:eu-repo'))]/substring-before(., '-')
```

**When this XPath 2.0 expression is evaluated off the top element of the last XML document (nearest above), the wanted years are produced**:

```
2012 2011
```

**XSLT 2.0 - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:sequence select=
   "*[not(starts-with(., 'info:eu-repo'))]/substring-before(., '-')"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the last XML document, the XPath expression is evaluated and the result of this evaluation is copied to the output**:

```
2012 2011
```

---

**IV. The Most General and Difficult case**:

Now, let's have this XML document:

```
<t xmlns:dc="some:dc">
    <dc:date>info:eu-repo/date/embargoEnd/2013-06-12</dc:date>
    <dc:date>2012-07-04</dc:date>
    <dc:date>info:eu-repo/date/embargoEnd/2013-06-12</dc:date>
    <dc:date>2011-07-05</dc:date>
    <dc:date>*/date/embargoEnd/2014-06-12</dc:date>
</t>
```

We still want to get the year part of all `dc:date` elements whose string value doesn't start with 'info:eu-repo'. However none of the previous solutions work correctly with the last `dc:date` element above.

**Remarkably, the wanted data can still be produced by a single XPAth 2.0 expression**:

```
for $s in
      *[not(starts-with(., 'info:eu-repo'))]/tokenize(.,'/')[last()]
     return
       substring-before($s, '-')
```

**When this expression is evaluated off the top element of the above XML document, the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
2012 2011 2014
```

**And this is the XSLT 2.0 - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:sequence select=
   "for $s in
      *[not(starts-with(., 'info:eu-repo'))]/tokenize(.,'/')[last()]
     return
       substring-before($s, '-')
   "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```