# how to do an if like statement or equivalent in XSLT

Tags: xslt

Is it possible to write out xml based on an "if" "Like" statement or the equivalent of in xslt?

I have an element named "cust_code"
If the element starts with a "HE" then I want to write it out, otherwise jump to the next.

Is it possible?

Comment: Duplicate of [How to implement if-else statement in XSLT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13622338/how-to-implement-if-else-statement-in-xslt)

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please provide a [mcve]. XSLT does not have a "*jump to the next*" mechanism. Judging from your description, it would be much more elegant to apply templates only to the nodes you want to "*write out*" to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

`If` statements exist in XSLT.

```
<xsl:if test="...">
    ...
</xsl:if>
```

But this is a simple `if`, with no alternative.

If you want an equivalent to `if ... else ...` or `switch ... case ...`, you need to use the following:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="...">
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

You can have as many `when` cases as necessary.

Links: [w3school - if](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_if.asp) and [w3school - choose](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_choose.asp).

As to having an element starting with a specific string, look at the function `starts-with`. You can find a good example in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12508566/xsl-if-test-starts-with) (just omit the `not` from the main answer, as their tests was to find strings **not** starting with a particular string). You can also look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26217002/how-to-use-starts-with-contains-and-ends-with-in-xpath-to-find-the-xml-n) for more information.

Comment: thank you.
I have done an if statement before in xslt and that works fine.

In this instance though I want to see if the element value has the first 2 characters "HE" , the full element value will be something like "He2345567"

I only want to write if it begins with "HE"

Comment: @NathanFuller The other SO answers I linked show how to use the `starts-with` function. So for example, you could do `<xsl:if test="starts-with(myNode, 'HE')"> ... </xsl:if>`.

Comment: Thank you Anton

that is exactly what I needed.
Works fantastically.